# Delay in function calling

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(id_lastchild).click();
    $("#upload_download_doc").hide();
}, 150);
setTimeout(function () {
    $(id_lastchild).click();
    $("#upload_download_doc").hide();
}, 100);
```

but I want to do above in a function like

```
function click_hide_Scroll(){
    $(id_lastchild).click();
    $("#upload_download_doc").hide();
}
```

Implementation which I am looking for is

`delay(100).click_hide_Scroll().delay(100).click_hide_Scroll();`

that means after a 100ms delay call the `click_hide_Scroll()` function and then after completion of it and another 100ms delay, call that function again.

Is it possible? Or is there any other code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `callback()`

```
function callAgain(){
    $(id_lastchild).click();
    $("#upload_download_doc").hide();
}

function click_hide_Scroll(callback){
        $(id_lastchild).click();
        $("#upload_download_doc").hide();
        setTimeout(callback, 100);
}

setTimeout(function() { click_hide_Scroll(callAgain)}, 100);
```

Comment: Thanx for this..it solved half problem..I have to pass parameter also `setTimeout(function () { click_hide_Scroll(callAgain, 3) }, 1000);` and `function callAgain(id) {
            alert("called " + id);
        }

        function click_hide_Scroll(callback, id) {
            setTimeout(callback(id), 5000);
        }` but it calls function immediately

Comment: @debin -   What mistake you done is you directly pass the parameter in setTimout like `setTimeout(callback(id), 5000);` so it execeuted immediately. pass as function like `setTimeout(function() {callback(id) }, 5000);`

Comment: thnx alot..now I understood what is happening :)